# (Bad Variable: Line 36) Please Help!

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

What have I done wrong here?, cause when I run my script and stop it after I set the variable, it says I have a bad variable

```
qmail.script: 36: read: : bad variable name.
```

Help would be much appreciated.

```
unset PASSWORD
unset CHARCOUNT
echo
echo -n "Please Enter a Password For VqAdmin, Roundcube and QmailAdmin.
Password: "
stty echo
CHARCOUNT=0
while IFS= read "$PROMPT" -p -r -s -n 
do
    #Enter - accept password
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\0' ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    #Backspace
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\177' ]] ; then
        if [ $CHARCOUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
            CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT-1))
            PROMPT=$'\b \b'
            PASSWORD="${PASSWORD%?}"
        else
            PROMPT=''
        fi
    else
        CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT+1))
        PROMPT='*'
        PASSWORD=$CHAR
    fi
done
stty echo
```

Comment: you don't even have 36 lines in your code lol.

Comment: it tells me after i type the password, but anyway something is wrong and i cant figure it out?, keep in mind i have multiple scripts that execute after this one (12 to be exact) and the code i posted is only part of the start for the script, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4):

I take it you're not showing all of the code, so `line 36` is really the `read` statement from the snippet you posted.

The `read` statement is wrong. IMHO you mean

```
read -p "$PROMPT" -r -s -n1 CHAR
```

- `$PROMPT` is the parameter for `-p`, either printing a '*' or nothing at input.
- `-n` needs a parameter too, telling how many characters to read at once.
- The variable `$CHAR` is used later, but it's never assigned to by `read`

Also `$PASSWORD` will contain only the last character, since you forgot to concatenate: `PASSWORD=$CHAR` should rather be

```
PASSWORD+=$CHAR
```

or

```
PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}${CHAR}
```

With this corrections, the code does what I think it's supposed to: Present a 'starred' password prompt.

---

**Upon request here the complete and corrected code snippet**

```
unset PASSWORD
unset CHARCOUNT
echo
echo -n "Please Enter a Password For VqAdmin, Roundcube and QmailAdmin.
Password: "
stty echo
CHARCOUNT=0
while IFS= read -p "$PROMPT" -r -s -n1 CHAR 
do
    #Enter - accept password
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\0' ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    #Backspace
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\177' ]] ; then
        if [ $CHARCOUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
            CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT-1))
            PROMPT=$'\b \b'
            PASSWORD="${PASSWORD%?}"
        else
            PROMPT=''
        fi
    else
        CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT+1))
        PROMPT='*'
        PASSWORD+=$CHAR
    fi
done
```

Judging from your comment, you did not write this code yourself (entirely) (?) and have some trouble understanding it. I won't explain to you line-by-line what it does. Sorry. I suggest you read around the web and come back with a specific questions should they arise. A good explanation of `read` and it's options is for example [given here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read).

General introductions to bash programming can be found for example at

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist

Comment: Ok, look i am new to this shell scripting stuff but i think how i did this i confused myself in a way thanks very much for the answer but what is it that i have to change for the code to work right?, because your right its the read im having an issue with and dident understand how to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Tony, I've added the complete code. I suggest you look at some tutorials and guides to learn bash a little better. Then, if specific questions arise, ask back!

Comment: No worries, thanks buddy, i appreciate you understanding im only trying to learn here :)